# Create multiple new documents with firebase batch

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so i have this array of objects i need to replicate using a loop so instead of calling create for all the document creations i decided to use firebase batch here my code:

```
const batch = firebase.firestore().batch();

          dataToBeReplicated.map((data)=>{

            var newData = data

            newData.name = "New replicated data"

            const newDataRef =  firebase.firestore().collection("name").doc()

            batch.set(newDataRef, { ...newData } );


          })

          await batch.commit()
```

now the code runs without an error but the data is not getting created.

i tried using the regular way like :

```
const result = firebase.firestore()
                .collection("name")
                .add({
                    ...newData
                });
```

and this works fine, but imagine if i have hundred data this will not be efficient that's why i am using batch.

so am i creating the batch correctly? is a problem with the code?

Comment: What does `dataToBeReplicated` contain exactly?  For all we know, it could be empty.  What have you tried in order to debug this? Have you tried using log statements to make sure each batch item is set the way you expect?

Comment: yes i logged the batch right after i do `batch.set` and the data iset is in there in the `_writes`  array

Comment: `dataToBeReplicated` is array of objects something like `[ {name:"John Doe",image:"image_url",id:3} ]`